# Once I found the region, How can I found the Area

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, graphing-functions

I have to find the area of the region bounded by $y = 4x^2$, the tangent line at $(3, 36)$ and the $x$-axis.

I found the equation of the tangent line, which is: $y = 24x-36$ 
Both functions meet at $x = 3$ , so I have enclosed the region I am working with. However, I don't know how to find the area since no function "dominates" the other. So, I tried to find the area under the curve between $\left[0,\frac 32\right]$ and then, I added the area under the curve between $\left[\frac 32, 3\right]$. My result was $\frac {81}{2}$ but the right answer is $9$.

I'd be grateful if you guys can help me realize what I did wrong.

Comment: [Here's what that region looks like.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9VMUH.jpg)

Comment: I see where you (probably) made your mistake. See the highlighted bit in my answer; you probably wrote $0$ instead of $\frac32$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, the equation of the tangent at $(3, 36)$ to the parabola: $y=4x^2$ 
$$y-36=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(3, 36)}(x-3)$$ 
$$y-36=24(x-3)\ \ or \ \ \ y=24x-36$$ 
The above tangent line intersects the x-axis at $\left(\frac 32, 0\right)$

Draw a diagram, drop a perpendicular from the point of tangency $(3, 36)$ to the x-axis at the point $(3, 0)$ & consider a vertical elementary slab of thickness $dx$  & height $y$ in the region bounded between parabola, tangent & the x-axis & move it from $x=0$ to $x=3$ covering bounded region & a region of right triangle, then the required area of bounded region
$$\int_{0}^{3}y\ dx-\text{area of right triangle}$$ 
$$=\int_{0}^{3}(4x^2)\ dx-\frac{1}{2}\left(3-\frac 32\right)(36)$$ 
$$=4\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{3}-27$$ 
$$=4\left[\frac{27}{3}-0\right]-27$$ 
$$=36-27=\color{red}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have this region:
[image: Region]

You want this calculation:
$$\int_0^{3/2}4x^2\operatorname d\!x+\int_{\color{Red}{3/2}}^3(4x^2-(24x-36))\operatorname d\!x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: An interesting property of a parabola $y=A x^2$ is that the tangent line at $(x,A x^2)$ meets the $x$-axis at $(x/2,0)$.

Comment: Yep. In fact, I've seen someone use this fact to find the area under a parabola! (In general, the tangent of $y=Ax^\alpha$ at $(x,Ax^\alpha)$ meets the $x$-axis at $(x-x/\alpha,0)$, I believe.)